# Template included with plugin doesn't return all posts for custom taxonomy

Tags: loop, templates, plugins-url

I'm in the process of developing a plugin with a custom page template (using `template_include`) with a loop that retrieves all posts with a custom taxonomy. I tested the code using the same templates files directly in the theme folder, the loop works as it should.

However, as a plugin, the page template fails to retrieve all posts. It only returns a single post. I've included the relevant loop code below:

```
<?php 
        // Retrieve all terms for the custom tax
        $helpterms = get_terms('ways_to_help');

        // Use wp_list_pluck to retrieve only the IDs for the terms
        $termID = wp_list_pluck( $helpterms, 'term_id' );

        $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
            'post_type' => 'post', 
            'orderby' => 'rand', 
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'ways_to_help',
                            'field' => 'term_id',
                            'terms' => $termID
                        ),
                    ), 
            ) 
       );
?>
<div id="ways-to-help">
  <h2>All Ways To Help</h2>
    <div class="help-container">
        <?php
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        ?>
        <?php
            // Using include_once instead of get_template_part for plugin
            include_once( 'content-ways-to-help.php' );
           // get_template_part( 'content-ways-to-help', get_post_format() );

        ?>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php fistulaf_social_share(); ?>
```

Now this same code works totally fine in the theme folder, retrieving all of the posts in the custom tax. I can't figure out why it's not retrieving the correct number of posts. The `posts_per_page => -1` should retrieve them all?

As per others suggestions I've included the plugin code for including the page template here as a gist: https://gist.github.com/tnog/9374375504a6cdfcf0af

Appreciate help from anyone who could elucidate this strange issue. Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code that you use to include the page template with

Comment: I just updated my question with a gist with the plugin code for including the page template.